# Putting own address in variable

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, casting

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    x = int(&x);

    int* q;
    q = &x;

    int* p;
    p = (int*)&x;

    int* w;
    w = (int*)x;

    cout << *p << endl << x << endl << *q << endl << *w << endl << p << endl << q << endl << w << endl << &x;

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

5762632
5762632
5762632
5762632
0057EE48
0057EE48
0057EE48
0057EE48

1. Is this step `x = int(&x)` valid ? Is there anything conceptually wrong about this?
2. How to visualize/interpret what happens when we write `p = (int*)&x` and `w = (int*)x`?

Also note that this program executes only when step 1 is written. If `x` does not contain its own address, then the program will show an error.

Comment: No, this isn’t valid when `int` smaller than a pointer.

Comment: Yes true. And what about the second question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this step x = int(&x) valid ?
>    Is there anything conceptually wrong about this?

The statement may be valid and could provoke undefined behavior.  All depends on the platform.

On many of the platforms I've worked with, the addresses were never signed.  They were always `unsigned` because the sign bit was needed to represent the full range of addresses.  In other words, I suggest:
  unsigned int x = (unsigned int) &x;

Again it's about the sign bit and how addresses are represented.

> How to visualize/interpret what happens when we write p = (int*)&x and w = (int*)x?

If you want to *print* an address, I suggest you use the pointer format:

```
  cout << ((void *) &x) << endl;
```

or

```
 printf("%p\n", &x);
```

I recommend using a *debugger* rather than printing out addresses.  The debugger allows you to examine the values in a pointer.  But there are times when printing out information is a better method (like when working with multiple tasks or multiple processors).